# Setting default application for text files in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to tweak my linux environment so that when I type a text file name on the command line and hit enter the file should be opened in Vim.

$: /tmp/file.txt

should open the file in Vim. This is similar to what happens on windows (where a text file is opened in notepad.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this in zsh, using alias -s, but I haven't heard of bash being able to do this. I use this in bash for .txt, .pdf, e.g. Note that this works when a file has the right extension. Extensions are not necessary in Linux.

Comment: Perusing the zsh man page(s): this would work: `alias -s txt=vim`.

Comment: edited, thx. Yes -g is for global alias; I use : for "| less", e.g., which I can add to commands.

Answer (score 1):

Since Linux recognizes files by their content and not by their name there is no reliable way of doing this. You can try [binfmt_misc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc), but that will most likely not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Gnome, you can alias `gnome-open` to `g` or something and use that to open files with the the default handler used by Gnome. Would that work for you?

The way you're suggesting sounds quite annoying. What if `/tmp/file.txt` was executable? Would you want it to open or run when you typed it's name and hit enter?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't. The first part of the line is the command it self. At least if you just what something very short to open a file using vim you can set an alias:
in your .bashrc if you use bash:

```
alias v="vim"
```

Comment: You need to remove the spaces around the equal sign.

Answer (score 0):

Ubiquité is correct that what you want is not supported in bash.  However, you can use the netrw support in vim 7 to browse directories!

Try this:

```
alias v="vim ."
v
```

A directory listing will show up.  Now you can do the following:

- Use `j/k` to go up & down
- Place cursor on a dir & press `enter` to explore it
- Place cursor on a file & press `enter` to edit it
- Use `-` to go up a dir
- Use `D` to delete a file or dir
- Use `R` to rename a file or dir
- Use `s` to change the sorting of items (name, time, size)
- Use `d` to create a dir
- Use `i` to cycle between listing formats (thin, long, wide, tree)
- Use `Ctrl-l` to refresh a directory listing

You can do a *lot* more with netrw too!  It can be used for remote file browsing over ssh.  For more info, check the help file with F1.

Comment: You need to remove the spaces around the equal sign.

Answer (score 0):

In cygwin, I use: `alias start=cygstart`
In ubuntu, I use: `alias start=xdg-open`

So, I can use `start /some/file/name` to do the default action in a Windows cmd shell or in a bash shell.